# How can I split a GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy aggregate exchange into the original exchanges?

Tags: kotlin, apache-camel, spring-camel

After aggregating exchanges using a `GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy` I need to split them back apart (to emit individual processing time metrics) into the original exchanges.

I tried splitting with the following but the resulting split exchange wraps the original exchange and puts it in the `Message` body.

Is it possible to split a `GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy` aggregate exchange into the original exchanges without the wrapper exchange? I need to use the original exchange properties and would like to do so with a SpEL expression.

```
.aggregate(constant(true), myGroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy)
    .completionInterval(1000)
    .completeAllOnStop()
    .process { /* do stuff */ }
.split(exchangeProperty(Exchange.GROUPED_EXCHANGE))
    .to(/* micrometer timer metric using SpEL expression */)
    // ^- the resulting split exchange is wrapped in another exchange
```

In the event that this isn't currently supported, I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement this behavior on my own without creating a custom `Splitter` processor for this single feature. I was hoping to somehow override the `SplitterIterable` that does the wrapping but it doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the [`GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy.html) does nothing else than create a [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of all [Exchanges](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html). The [Splitter EIP](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) on the other hand splits by default a List into the elements and puts the element into the message body. Therefore **you end up with an Exchange that contains an Exchange** in its body.

What you need is an AggregationStrategy that **collects all body Objects** in a List instead of all Exchanges.

You could try to use **Camels [`FlexibleAggregationStrategy`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/util/toolbox/FlexibleAggregationStrategy.html) that is configurable through a fluent API**.

new FlexibleAggregationStrategy()
                .storeInBody()
                .accumulateInCollection(ArrayList.class)
                .pick(new SimpleExpression("${body}"));

This should create an AggregationStrategy that extracts the body of every message (you can perhaps omit the pick method since body extraction is the pick default), collects them in a List and stores the aggregation in the message body.

To split this aggregate again, a simple `split(body())` should be enough.

#### EDIT due to comment

Yes, you are right, a **side effect of my solution** is that you lose properties and headers of the original messages because it only aggregates the message bodies.

What you want to do, is splitting the List of Exchanges back into the originals. i.e. the **Splitter must not create new Exchanges, but use the already present ones** and throw away the aggregated wrapper Exchange.

As far as I can see in the [source code of the Splitter](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/b9a3117f19dd19abd2ea8b789c42c3e86fe4c488/core/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/Splitter.java), this is **currently not possible**:

```
Exchange newExchange = ExchangeHelper.createCorrelatedCopy(copy, false);
...
if (part instanceof Message) {
    newExchange.setIn((Message) part);
} else {
    Message in = newExchange.getIn();
    in.setBody(part);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this will work for me because I believe your strategy would lose the properties on the original non-aggregated exchanges, which are required by the metrics library that I'm using (micrometer)

Comment: I extended my comment, unfortunately what you want seems to be not possible

Comment: yep agreed, it doesn't appear to be natively supported. I implemented a custom solution (below) that splits to a *nearly* identical state

Answer (score 0):

Per the accepted answer, it doesn't appear to be natively supported.

This custom processor will *unwrap* a split exchange (i.e. copying the nested exchange `Message` and properties to the root exchange). The unwrapped exchange will be *nearly* identical to the original -- it will retain all non-conflicting properties from the root exchange (e.g. `Splitter`-related properties like split index, etc.)

```
class ExchangeUnwrapper : Processor {

    override fun process(exchange: Exchange) {
        val wrappedExchange = exchange.`in`.body as Exchange
        ExchangeHelper.copyResultsPreservePattern(exchange, wrappedExchange)
    }
}

// Route.kt

from(...)
.aggregate(...)
.process { /* do things with aggregate */ }
.split(exchangeProperty(Exchange.GROUPED_EXCHANGE))
  .process(ExchangeUnwrapper())
  .process { /* do something with the original exchange */ }
.end()
```